# Combining results of multiple if statements in php

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a php file with two mysql queries and an if statement for each query. I'd like the final output to combine the two results and separate with a comma. Right now, the first if statement is working, but the second is not.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT round(AVG(cop),1) AS 'avg_cop' FROM table WHERE timestamp >= subdate((select max(timestamp) from table), interval 1 week)");
if ($result < 3.41)
    {
    $ret = "example text 1";
    } else {
    $ret = "na";
    }

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT round(AVG(temp),1) AS 'avg_temp' FROM table WHERE timestamp >= subdate((select max(timestamp) from table), interval 1 week)");
if ($result1 < 53)
    {
    $ret1 = "example text 2";
    } else {
    $ret1 = "na";
    }


echo $ret.", ".$ret1;
```

In this instance, I know that the first query results in a "1.1" value and the second results in a "69.4" value. But, the final result I get is "example text 1, example text 2" when it should be "example text 1, na". Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `mysql_query(..) or die(mysql_error())` will tell you why your second query is not working. Do a little re-search before asking anything here

Comment: `mysql_query` doesn't return the result of your query.

Comment: I am very new to this and was researching for quite awhile before I decided to post. Sorry but I did not post the die part of my code... it was already in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_query` doesn't return the row itself, [it returns a resource](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) that you need to pass into a function like [mysql_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to deal with the table result; you can't just simply use the return value from mysql_query. 
It would also probably be better if you just combined the SQL queries into one.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT round(AVG(cop),1) AS 'avg_cop', round(AVG(temp),1) AS 'avg_temp' FROM table WHERE timestamp >= subdate((select max(timestamp) from table), interval 1 week)");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row['avg_cop'] < 3.41)
{
    $ret = "example text 1";
} else {
    $ret = "na";
}

if ($row['avg_temp'] < 53)
{
    $ret1 = "example text 2";
} else {
    $ret1 = "na";
}

echo $ret.", ".$ret1;
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I am new to this and trying to learn as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

$result and $result1 are currently strings. You want to add:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ... // unchanged");
$result = floatval($result)
if ($result < 3.41)
```

and for $result1

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT ... // unchanged");
$result1 = floatval($result1)
if ($result1 < 53.0) // note the addition of the .0 to compare one float to another
```

Comment: In general, try doing a var_dump($result) and var_dump($result1) to see what type and value they have if the if statement is not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use MYSQL it has deprecated since PHP 5, use [MYSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead; they are much safer a provide you with improved features.

It is also good pratice to assign a null value to a PHP variable before assigning it a value, especially in this case (`$ret =""` then you may change the value).

Finally, the results from `mysql_query()` is a resource, you need to iterate through it to get the proper values:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):
    //Do something with $row['avg_temp'];
endwhile;
```

Hope this helps!